# Отдача файла из PHP без создания самого файла

Tags: php

Генерирую набор данных в PHP и хочу дать возможность пользователю скачать все данные одним файлом.

Набор данных варьируется от пользователя к пользователю (с учетом времени суток, фазы луны и прочих случайных факторов), поэтому создавать физические файлы не имеет смысла.

Собственно вопрос: как отдавать файл средствами PHP без создания файла на диске?

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? А что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так вот не понимаю, как сделать так что бы создавался txt файл с занесенными туда данными. Т.е. не создавался а скачивался пользователю с уже готовыми данными

Comment: Как в php получить данные из базы данных знаете?

Comment: да у меня, все данные у меня в массиве. Что бы получить каждое прохожусь foreach. Но вот как запихать в файл

Comment: Думаю для начала вам стоит локализовать вопрос. Сейчас попробую помочь с этим ;)

Comment: Я попробовал локализовать проблему в вашем вопросе. Если я неверно ее понял, просто откатите мои правки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file_content = "";
foreach ($data_array as $row)
    $file_content .= "$row[name]\t$row[age]\t$row[gender]\r\n";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; charset=utf-8; filename=\"file.txt\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($file_content));
echo $file_content;
```

Comment: Стоит добавить код с определением переменных `$file_length` и `$file_content`

Comment: А если все данные отдаются через AJAX, то файл не скачивается. Как быть?

Comment: Это уже не относится к PHP, [вот такой вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request).